# Deduplicating code in slightly different functions

Tags: python, code-duplication

I have two very similar loops, and these two contain an inner loop that is very similar to a third loop (eh... :) ). Illustrated with code it looks close to this:

```
# First function
def fmeasure_kfold1(array, nfolds):
    ret = []

    # Kfold1 and kfold2 both have this outer loop
    for train_index, test_index in KFold(len(array), nfolds):
        correlation = analyze(array[train_index])

        for build in array[test_index]:  # <- All functions have this loop

            # Retrieved tests is calculated inside the build loop in kfold1
            retrieved_tests = get_tests(set(build['modules']), correlation)

            relevant_tests = set(build['tests'])
            fval = calc_f(relevant_tests, retrieved_tests)
            if fval is not None:
                ret.append(fval)

    return ret

# Second function
def fmeasure_kfold2(array, nfolds):
    ret = []

    # Kfold1 and kfold2 both have this outer loop
    for train_index, test_index in KFold(len(array), nfolds):
        correlation = analyze(array[train_index])

        # Retrieved tests is calculated outside the build loop in kfold2
        retrieved_tests = _sum_tests(correlation)

        for build in array[test_index]:  # <- All functions have this loop

            relevant_tests = set(build['tests'])
            fval = calc_f(relevant_tests, retrieved_tests)
            if fval is not None:
                ret.append(fval)

    return ret

# Third function
def fmeasure_all(array):
    ret = []
    for build in array:  # <- All functions have this loop

        relevant = set(build['tests'])
        fval = calc_f2(relevant)  # <- Instead of calc_f, I call calc_f2
        if fval is not None:
            ret.append(fval)

    return ret
```

The first two functions only differ in the manner, and at what time, they calculate `retrieved_tests`. The third function differs from the inner loop of the first two functions in that it calls `calc_f2`, and doesn't make use of `retrieved_tests`.

In reality the code is more complex, but while the duplication irked me I figured I could live with it. However, lately I've been making changes to it, and it's annoying to have to change it in two or three places at once.

How can I merge the duplicated code? The only way I could think of involved introducing classes, which introduces a lot of boilerplate, and I would like to keep the functions as pure functions if possible.

---

**Edit**

This is the contents of `calc_f` and `calc_f2`:

```
def calc_f(relevant, retrieved):
    """Calculate the F-measure given relevant and retrieved tests."""
    recall = len(relevant & retrieved)/len(relevant)
    prec = len(relevant & retrieved)/len(retrieved)
    fmeasure = f_measure(recall, prec)

    return (fmeasure, recall, prec)


def calc_f2(relevant, nbr_tests=1000):
    """Calculate the F-measure given relevant tests."""
    recall = 1
    prec = len(relevant) / nbr_tests
    fmeasure = f_measure(recall, prec)

    return (fmeasure, recall, prec)
```

`f_measure` calculates the [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) of precision and recall.

Basically, `calc_f2` takes a lot of shortcuts since no retrieved tests are needed.

Comment: How do `calc_f` and `calc_f2` differ?

Comment: I edited the question to add info on those functions.

Comment: It'so dd that `calc_f2` takes two argument (and it uses the second argument, too) but `fmeasure_all` calls it with just one argument. I suppose that's a consequence of the "simplifying" the code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It's also a consequence of my being on the fence whether to make that argument an optional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Having a common function that takes an extra parameter that controls where to compute `retrieved_tests` would work too.

e.g.

```
def fmeasure_kfold_generic(array, nfolds, mode):
    ret = []

    # Kfold1 and kfold2 both have this outer loop
    for train_index, test_index in KFold(len(array), nfolds):
        correlation = analyze(array[train_index])

        # Retrieved tests is calculated outside the build loop in kfold2
        if mode==2:
            retrieved_tests = _sum_tests(correlation)

        for build in array[test_index]:  # <- All functions have this loop
            # Retrieved tests is calculated inside the build loop in kfold1
            if mode==1:
                retrieved_tests = get_tests(set(build['modules']), correlation)

            relevant_tests = set(build['tests'])
            fval = calc_f(relevant_tests, retrieved_tests)
            if fval is not None:
                ret.append(fval)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write the inner loops each as a function, and then have the outer loop as a separate function that receives the others as an argument. This is something close to what is done in sorting functions (that receive the function that should be used to compare two elements).

Of course, the hard part is to find what exactly is the common part between all functions, which is not always simple.

Answer (score 0):

Typical solution would be to identify parts of algorithm and use [Template method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) where different stages would be implemented in subclasses. I do not understand your code at all, but I assume there would be methods like `makeGlobalRetrievedTests()` and `makeIndividualRetrievedTests()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach the problem inside-out: by factoring out the innermost loop. This works well with a 'functional' style (as well as 'functional programming'). It seems to me that if you generalize `fmeasure_all` a bit you could implement all three functions in terms of that. Something like

```
def fmeasure(builds, calcFn, retrieveFn):
    ret = []
    for build in array:
        relevant = set(build['tests'])
        fval = calcFn(relevant, retrieveFn(build))
        if fval is not None:
            ret.append(fval)

    return ret
```

This allows you to define:

```
def fmeasure_kfold1(array, nfolds):
    ret = []

    # Kfold1 and kfold2 both have this outer loop
    for train_index, test_index in KFold(len(array), nfolds):
        correlation = analyze(array[train_index])

        ret += fmeasure(array[test_index], calc_f,
                        lambda build: get_tests(set(build['modules']), correlation))

    return ret


def fmeasure_kfold2(array, nfolds):
    ret = []

    # Kfold1 and kfold2 both have this outer loop
    for train_index, test_index in KFold(len(array), nfolds):
        correlation = analyze(array[train_index])

        # Retrieved tests is calculated outside the build loop in kfold2
        retrieved_tests = _sum_tests(correlation)

        ret += fmeasure(array[test_index], calc_f, lambda _: retrieved_tests)

    return ret


def fmeasure_all(array):
    return fmeasure(array,
                    lambda relevant, _: calc_f2(relevant),
                    lambda x: x)
```

By now, `fmeasure_kfold1` and `fmeasure_kfold2` look awfully similiar. They mostly differ in how `fmeasure` is called, so we can implement a generic `fmeasure_kfoldn` function which centralizes the iteration and collecting the results:

```
def fmeasure_kfoldn(array, nfolds, callable):
    ret = []
    for train_index, test_index in KFold(len(array), nfolds):
        correlation = analyze(array[train_index])
        ret += callable(array[test_index], correlation)
    return ret
```

This allows defining `fmeasure_kfold1` and `fmeasure_kfold2` very easily:

```
def fmeasure_kfold1(array, nfolds):
    def measure(builds, correlation):
        return fmeasure(builds, calc_f, lambda build: get_tests(set(build['modules']), correlation))
    return fmeasure_kfoldn(array, nfolds, measure)


def fmeasure_kfold2(array, nfolds):
    def measure(builds, correlation):
        retrieved_tests = _sum_tests(correlation)
        return fmeasure(builds, calc_f, lambda _: retrieved_tests)
    return fmeasure_kfoldn(array, nfolds, measure)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks very close to what I was looking for. I'll give it a whirl and see if it works for me.